# How to know if Rhythmbox is playing music or something else

Tags: python, rhythmbox

I'm trying to solve a bug in this [plugin](https://github.com/dmo60/lLyrics/blob/master/lLyrics/lLyrics.py). I want to show the sidebar only when playing music (not podcast or radio). My problem is I don't know what's the user is listening to. Can someone provide me with a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the code, APIs, documentation? What have you tried so far? How exactly did that fail? See [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Yes I have read the APIs documentation but it's not helpful because I don't know where to search. The API doc is not explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what is currently playing you'll need to:

1. obtain the shell
2. obtain the Rhythmbox Shell-Player from the shell.
3. Get the playing entry from the ShellPlayer
4. Find what the type the entry is.

Lets go step-by-step

**Rhythmbox Shell**

The [shell](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/RB.Shell.html) is a property of the plugin - `self.props.shell`.  So lets save the shell with `self.shell = self.props.shell`

**Rhythmbox Shell Player**

The [shell player](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/RB.ShellPlayer.html) is part of the shell properties - `player = self.shell.props.shell_player`

**Playing Entry**

The playing entry is found by interrogating the [shell-player](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/RB.ShellPlayer.html)

`entry = player.get_playing_entry()

**Entry Type**

From the [entry](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/RB.RhythmDBEntry.html) you can get the entry-type:

`entrytype = entry.get_entry_type()`

From the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/rhythmbox/stable/RhythmDBEntryType.html) - you'll probably just need to test that the entry-type is *Song* i.e. `entrytype.get_name()` - other types are used for additional play streams.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that next week. When I try `entrytype = entry.get_entry_type()` in python console I got an error that say that the function doesn't exist!

Comment: I've corrected the link to the entry type documentation - I've tested this on RB 3.0 and this works just fine.

Comment: Thanks it worked, maybe the last time I haven't played any song so I got None for entrytype